# Android: Why won't this code run in onCreate, or how can I make it work without a thread?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have this piece of code that runs alright when I put it in Eclipse, but for some reason it does not want to execute when I put it in an activity's onCreate method in Android studio.

Here is the code:

```
public class ItemListView extends AppCompatActivity{
    String itemURL;
    int listSize;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

          Bundle itemData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(itemData==null){
            return;
        }

        //Gets URL from search bar
        itemURL = itemData.getString("itemURL");

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rx+390&sprefix=rx+390%2Caps%2C166&crid=2MTUBA4KGNY06").get();
            String link = doc.select("h2#s-result-count").first().text();
            System.out.println(link);
            System.out.println(link.substring(1));
            if (link.substring(1, 2).equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("run1");
                listSize = Integer.parseInt(link.substring(2, 3));
                System.out.println(listSize);
                try {
                    listSize = Integer.parseInt(link.substring(2, 4));
                    System.out.println(listSize);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("run2");
                listSize = Integer.parseInt(link.substring(0, 1));
                System.out.println(listSize);
                try {
                    listSize = Integer.parseInt(link.substring(0, 2));
                    System.out.println(listSize);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        System.out.println("listSize: " +listSize);
        ...
    }
}
```

I need listSize to create a variable array depending on the URL, but when I print the value to make sure it's working it always gives me 0. I have tried running the code in a separate Java Class with AsyncTask and it works, but by the time the code executes in onPostExecute, it's too late since the class above has already tried to initialize the array.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a callback to allow you to initialize variable `onPostExecute`:

```
interface OnCallCompleteCallBack {
    void onCallComplete(int listSize);
}
```

In your `AsyncTask` do this:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask < ... > {
    // Maintain a ref to callback
    OnCallCompleteCallBack callback;

    MyTask(OnCallCompleteCallBack callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onCallComplete(listSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Make your `Activity` implement `OnCallCompleteCallBack` and start the `AsyncTask` like this:

```
new MyTask(this).execute();
```

You can then use the value inside your activity's implementation of `onCallComplete()`

Comment: This seems to have worked! Thanks! I also edited some of your code in the onPostExecute method since using a parameter int would make it so the method wouldn't override anymore. Changing it back to Void aVoid seems to have fixed this, however

Comment: Also, would you mind going a bit more in depth as to how this interface fixes my issues?

Comment: Sure...this is usually a common pattern to do something after the completion of an async piece of work. So what happens is, your `onCreate` executes the `AsyncTask` and completes and the `AsyncTask` is running on a separate thread. You need a way to let your activity know that the call has been completed, this is where a having the asynctask "callback" your activity helps.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. One last question, if I have more variables inside MyTask(i.e. Title, URL), and I already have an array list of those items created, what is the best way to access the title and the URL inside the CustomAdapter using your method? Do I create another interface with the parameters of (String title, String URL)?

Comment: If your need to pass more data you can add additional parameters to this callback itself. If the num of params are a lot, then create a class and make that as the parameter of your callback

Comment: I don't think that works. Since when you create a List View Adapter you need to override the getView method, which then returns the view to get a ListView. If try to make an onCallComplete method as I have, it doesn't work because my code needs to be on getView in order to return the adapter in the first place.

Comment: You don't even `setAdapter()` till you have your dataset to populate the listview. In on call complete pass all the data you need through the constructor and then call `setAdapter()`

Comment: I do that. In my activity, I create the array and only then do setAdapter(). However, my customAdapter still does not get the data necessary to run

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, just a few observations:

- Naming your activity ItemListView seems wrong (an `Activity` is not a `View`).
- You should never perform networks calls on the UI thread.
- If you want to log, you should use `Log` instead of `System.out.println()`.

And now to the answer. You should execute the code that fetches the data in an `AsyncTask` (as you mentions it works). Once the data is fetched, you should update array and at that point update the UI in `onPostExecute()`.

Android works pretty well using the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (Model-View–Controller) pattern and your problem is a classic case where you need to update the model using data from the server and update the views accordingly. The activity represents controller in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the topic in android developer site [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#intro), Read the section "Introducing Network Operations on a Separate Thread" - To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread; if you don't, a NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown.

Thanks Ashish